# CSS Safari Bug?

Tags: css, safari

on this site:

http://dev.identworx.de/iacs/partners/

the boxes havn't the same sequences. I have this problem with **Safari only**.

In other browsers it looks perfect.

What can i do?

Thanks, B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove  **.widget + .widget** class and add 2 classes .**widget:nth-child(2n)** and **.widget:last-child** also change the **.widget** class styling.
**It's working on all major browsers so you can check it.**

```
/*REMOVE THIS CLASS*/ 
.widget + .widget {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/*ADD THIS CLASS*/ 
.widget:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}

/*CHANGE THIS CLASS*/
.widget {
    border-top: 2px solid #6277B3 !important;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

/*ADD THIS CLASS*/ 
.widget:last-child {
     margin-bottom: 80px;
}
```